# Can I make a pH 7 buffer from phosphoric acid and sodium hydroxide?

Tags: ph, solutions

I am an electronics guy with not so much knowledge of chemistry.
I would like to prepare a pH 7 buffer to test pH meters.

All web references I have found so far describing how to make a phosphate buffer use
disodium phosphate (Na<sub>2</sub>HPO<sub>4</sub>) and Monosodium phosphate (NaH<sub>2</sub>PO<sub>4</sub>) as ingredients.

I have a good supply of 85% phosphoric acid and solid sodium hydroxide. Can I make a pH 7 buffer from these ingredients instead or is there a catch?

Comment: Generally you'd get a standard solution to calibrate your meter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with little trouble.  The only caveats:

- Make a stock solution of phosphoric acid and also of NaOH.  When you add them to each other to make your buffer, heating could be a problem, much moreso than if you were using the mono- and di-basic sodium phosphate salts.  So you may want to cool on ice when mixing these compounds.
- You can calculate approximately how much NaOH and phosphoric acid to mix in order to get a pH 7 result, but it's best to use a pH meter to verify that you've reached pH 7.